# How to update selected rows in ListView

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, listview

I have listview in asp.net web form . I want to select rows and update selected after button click.
For this i want to use Checkbox/CheckboxList  . But i don't understand how to send information about row or from column in selected row to Checkbox/CheckboxList item .
How can i select rows, and update them , using Checkbox/CheckboxList ?
I use Asp.net Linq Entity Framework.
My code

```html
  <asp:Button ID="ButtonTest" runat ="server" OnClick="ButtonTest_Click" />
<asp:ListView ID="ListView2" ItemType="DocCat.Models.ReqInf" SelectMethod="GetReqF" OnItemDataBound="ListView2_ItemDataBound"
            DataKeyNames="requestN" EnableViewState="true" runat="server" UpdateMethod="ListView2_UpdateItem" DeleteMethod="ListView2_DeleteItem" InsertMethod="ListView2_InsertItem">
            <LayoutTemplate>
                <div class="outerContainer" style="overflow: scroll">
                    <table id="docTable">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>
                                   Выбрать
                                </th>
                                <th>First</th>
                                <th>Request</th>
                                <th>Third</th>
                                <th>Four</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody runat="server" id="itemPlaceholder"></tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
               
            </LayoutTemplate>

            <ItemTemplate>
                <tr>
                    <td> <asp:CheckBoxList runat="server" ID="CheckNew" ><asp:ListItem>Выбрать</asp:ListItem></asp:CheckBoxList></td>
                    <td>
               </td>
                    <td><%# Item.BirthDate.Date%></td>
                    <td><%# Item.F1 %></td>
                    <td><%# Item.F2 %></td>
                    <td><%# Item.F3 %></td>
                </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:ListView>
```

Selected rows don't display in Checkboxlist items and in string selectedItems :

```css
        CheckBoxList cblRoles = ListView2.Items[0].FindControl("CheckNew") as CheckBoxList;
        
        string selectedItems = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < cblRoles.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            if (cblRoles.Items[i].Selected)
            {
                selectedItems = selectedItems + cblRoles.Items[i].Value + ",";
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was to find checkbox, i just missed this :

```
  foreach (ListViewDataItem item in this.ListView2.Items)
                {
                    if (item.ItemType == ListViewItemType.DataItem)
                    {
```

and all is working .

My button_click method:

```
            List<int> ls = new List<int>();

            {

                foreach (ListViewDataItem item in this.ListView2.Items)
                {
                    if (item.ItemType == ListViewItemType.DataItem)
                    {
                        CheckBox chkRow = item.FindControl("CheckBox") as CheckBox;

                        if (chkRow.Checked)
                        {
                            int request = int.Parse((item.FindControl("FirstFind") as Label).Text.Trim());

                            ls.Add(request);


                        }
                    }
                }


                repository.Approved(ls, newstat);
```

Update Method

```
  public void Approved(List<int> list,int stat )
        {


            var friends = context.Requery.Where(f => list.Contains(f.parametr)).ToList();

            friends.ForEach(a =>
            {
                a.par1 = 0;
                a.par2 = stat;
            });


            context.SaveChanges();

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently used this kind of UI. First I created Table UI, I created populate Table method in my code behind.I used ADO.net for Data Access.

**Note**: Create stored procs for getting the data and updating the data after button click.

Step1: Write Populate Table method in that create object for checkbox but I used radio Button.

```
                   using (mTableRow = new HtmlTableRow()){
                    {

                        #region Radio Button

                        using (HtmlTableCell lTableCell = new HtmlTableCell())
                        {
                            RadioButton mradioButton = new RadioButton();
                                mradioButton.ID = "Radio" + listInfo.ID;

                                mradioButton.GroupName = "rowSelector1";
                                mradioButton.AutoPostBack = true;
                                mradioButton.Checked = false;

                                mradioButton.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(AvailableRadioButton_CheckedChanged);

                                lTableCell.Attributes["class"] = "RadioButton";
                                lTableCell.Controls.Add(mradioButton);

                                mTableRow.Cells.Add(lTableCell);

                                #endregion
                         // add all the remaining columns
                           // add table row to the table.
```

Step2: Create a method for event click of Checkbox.

Comment: NOTE: Here your checkbox ID should be unique. So you concatenate your primary key column in your table and also you have to primary key in your query or stored procedure. Then only you are able to select the row.